# How to add dynamic element in a table column without affecting other element in same column

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table in which column elements have text in them. I click a button and all the text elements become input elements. Based on a condition, there is a button displayed next to the input field.

What i have to do is display a button with an icon in the same column, next to the input field. I have done this, however the result is not as expected.

[image: This is what I am getting]
This is what I am getting.

[image: This is what I want] This is what I am looking for.

```
<td id="id119ae">
<form class="mytemp" id="form19af" method="post" action="./Application"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="hidden" name="form19af_hf_0" id="form19af_hf_0"></div>

    <div style="padding:5px; border-width:0px;background-color: #ffffbb" id="editContainer19b0">
    <button style="display:none;" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">
        <span class="fa fa-bolt"></span>
    </button>
        <input value="Account test" name="editContainer:edit" id="edit1923">

    </div>
</form>
```

This is the code that I currently have that gives me the first result. The layout is causing some problems. I need better layout suggestions or ways to fix this.

Comment: "without affecting" is this more of a css/layout question?

Comment: The button that i showed is dynamic. initially it is not present.. that is why the table size is limited to the size of the input element. A user does an action and then the 'bolt button' is displayed. I want it to come next to the input box( in same line). Not like how I am getting in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Use inputgroup classes to show the buttons adjacent to input type
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Comment: this does not help me . The button is added dynamically and the column width does not change when it is added. Instead it adds the button on top so that the column width does not change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unique solution for your request.

It depends on how you are designing? Are you considering the responsiveness? Are you using fixed width? or even are you using a library or framework like Bootstrap?

By the way, I think this one works for you:
use the percentage of width for your input and button.
For example:

```
<button style="display:none; width: 10%;" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">
   <span class="fa fa-bolt"></span>
</button>
<input value="Account test" style="width:80%" name="editContainer:edit" id="edit1923">
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was set min-width for the table. The percentage did not help me since it was dynamic. For some reason it was not taking that into account when the new element was added and the button always came in the wrong place.

I set the min-width for that column to 250 px . I tried to set it to say 30% but that did not work either.

solution: use min-width in the header elements. that sets the entire table to follow the least width.